# Edit Button in React Datatable Component with ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to pass id in edit button of column cell in reactJS datatable component?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Dhwani. Please post your code. It's too broad right now.

Comment: What's the exact package name you using @Dhwani Shah. ? There are quite a lot of data table components out there in npm registry

Comment: I have used react-data-table-component package in my application

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [cell property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component#react-data-table-component) of the Columns.

```
const columns = [
{
 name: "Name",
 selector: "name",
 sortable: true,
},
{
 name: "Phone",
 selector: "phone",
 sortable: true,
 right: true,
},
{
key: "action",
text: "Action",
className: "action",
width: 100,
align: "left",
sortable: false,
cell: (record) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        onClick={() => {
          onEdit(record);
        }}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
 },
},
];
```

In the onEdit method, you can manipulate the data or make the axios call and update the state to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using "react-table" npm package. Without knowing your requirement exactly, it is bit hard to suggest use the package I have mentioned above.

[React Table - npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table)

You can just have a look and see whether this is suitable for your requirement.